# Intrigue.io with Docker

Tags: docker

I'm attempting to set up [intrigue](https://github.com/intrigueio/intrigue-core/) on linux mint, and to set up the development environment I'm using docker. I was able to successfully install it

> sudo apt-get install docker.io

Currently I'm following a [guide](https://intrigue.io/2017/03/07/using-intrigue-core-with-docker/) which is supposed to describe how to do all of this. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to match up. Here are the commands the guide is having me run:

```
git clone https://github.com/intrigueio/intrigue-core
cd intrigue-core
docker build .
docker run -i -t -p 7777:7777
```

Then it says that postgresql, redis, and intrigue-io should all start. It works up to the very last command. After building, I try to run and get this error:

> "docker run" requires at least 1 argument(s).

It's not as if the guide is complicated to follow, so I'm just wondering if there is something I'm missing. Is the guide downright incorrect?

Comment: https://forums.manning.com/posts/list/37887.page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to write at least the name of what service you want to run.

But I see they define a `docker-compose` file, so it might be even easier if you just install it and then run `docker-compose up` (you can add a `-d` in the end to make it run as a deamon)